# Adding a new view on top of an existing view

Tags: ios, user-interface

I want to add a view called anotherView on top of self.view. But I don't want anotherView to be a subview. Is this possible?

I want anotherView to be at the top of the page and push the contents of self.view down accordingly (without having to change the y or height values.

I have the following and it doesn't work:

```
UIView *anotherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 80)];
anotherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

[self.view insertSubview:anotherView aboveSubview:self.view];
```

The box is simply on top of the existing view.

Comment: you can add your anotherView as subview of one ViewController's view, then present it.

Answer (score 0):

Any visible view is subview of some other view or window.

But you can add anotherView to

```
self.view.superview
```

or even

```
self.view.window
```

or create new UIWindow object and add your subview to this window

Comment: How would you push the existing view down to make room for anotherView?

Comment: Not sure I understood you correctly. UIView object can contain any numbers of subviews. The last added via addSubview view will be the top one. But you can also use UIView's methods `- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview`, `insertSubview:belowSubview:` and `insertSubview:atIndex:` to manage subview's Z-position

Comment: I tried using `-(void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview`, but it does not push siblingSubview down.

Comment: It is very strange. You should check that your anotherView is created correctly and has correct size.

Comment: You can add to question your code if you think it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to present anotherView modally? That way you can make it to appear on top of everything being a completly new view controller. Ex:

[self presentModalViewController:anotherView animated:YES];

assuming of course anotherView is a subclass of UIViewController and has its own View property. Because if anotherView is just subclass of UIView then you can't present it without being a subview of the current View Controller.

EDIT:
Oh yes, you can just pass a nil to the completion block:

```
[self presentViewController:anotherView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I get a warning that is it deprecated.

Comment: `- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion` should be used instead

Comment: I just updated my answer to give you the latest piece of code to present a modal view controller.

Comment: I get the following error when I use presentViewController. `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView modalPresentationStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc4dac90'`

Comment: Notice that this method should be called on the self reference not self.view Check the updated answer.

Comment: I still get that same issue with the self reference.